# Anysoftkeyboard keyboard switching issue

Tags: java, android, xml, android-softkeyboard

When i switch to eng_16keys.xml keyboard layout and press 123 it jump back to symbols.xml instead to symbols_16keys.xml which is already define in KeyboardSwitcher.java.

```
case SYMBOLS_KEYBOARD_REGULAR_INDEX:
if (AnyApplication.getConfig().use16KeysSymbolsKeyboards())
 keyboard = new GenericKeyboard(mContext, R.xml.symbols_16keys, R.xml.symbols,       R.string.symbols_keyboard, "symbols_keyboard", mode);
                else
                    keyboard = new GenericKeyboard(mContext, R.xml.symbols, R.string.symbols_keyboard, "symbols_keyboard", mode, false);
                    break;
```

but it not working there is not preference setting for that.
I simply want that  eng_16keys.xml switch to symbols_16keys.xml not symbols.xml which my current keyboard is eng_16keys.xml.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

Open a bug on this at AnySoftKeyboard's Github repo: https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard/issues